# How to read CSV files inside a loop using VBScript

Tags: csv, vbscript

I have 2 CSV files as shown below.

`TEAMLIST.csv`:

```
empid,name
54321,xyz
12345,abc
```

`DATA.csv`:

```
heading1,head2,head3,head4
54321-Process : GDPR_WBT,54321,Process : GDPR_WBT,TRUE
12345-Process : GDPR_WBT,12345,Process : GDPR_WBT,TRUE
54321-Fire Safety,54321,Fire Safety,FALSE
12345-Fire Safety,12345,Fire Safety,TRUE
```

Below is my entire VBScript code. The problem is that the inner loop is working fine but the outer loop is taking only the first record [54321,xyz] and not all records. Not able to understand why.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fs
Dim fs2
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fs2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim EMPLOYEE
Dim DATA

Set EMPLOYEE = fs.OpenTextFile("TEAMLIST.csv")
Set DATA = fs2.OpenTextFile("DATA.csv")

Dim counter, line, EMP_ARRAY
Dim counter2, line2, DATA_ARRAY

counter = 0
counter2 = 0

Do While Not EMPLOYEE.AtEndOfStream
    line = EMPLOYEE.ReadLine
    counter = counter + 1

    If counter > 1 Then
        EMP_ARRAY = Split(line, ",")

        Do While Not DATA.AtEndOfStream '### DATA LOOP STARTS ###
            line2 = DATA.ReadLine
            counter2 = counter2 + 1

            If counter2 > 1 Then
                DATA_ARRAY = Split(line2, ",")

                If EMP_ARRAY(0) = DATA_ARRAY(1) Then
                    If DATA_ARRAY(2) = "Process : GDPR_WBT" Then
                        If DATA_ARRAY(3) = "" Then
                            DATA_ARRAY(3) = "FALSE"
                        End If
                        WScript.Echo EMP_ARRAY(0) & "--" & EMP_ARRAY(1) & "--" & DATA_ARRAY(2) & "--" & DATA_ARRAY(3)
                    End If

                    If DATA_ARRAY(2) = "Fire Safety" Then
                        If DATA_ARRAY(3) = "" Then
                            DATA_ARRAY(3) = "FALSE"
                        End If
                        WScript.Echo EMP_ARRAY(0) & "--" & EMP_ARRAY(1) & "--" & DATA_ARRAY(2) & "--" & DATA_ARRAY(3)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Loop '### DATA LOOP ENDS ###
    End If
Loop

EMPLOYEE.Close
DATA.Close
Set EMPLOYEE = Nothing
Set DATA = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
Set fs2 = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first iteration of the outer loop the inner loop has already read `DATA.csv` to the end. To "rewind" that file for each iteration of the outer loop you need to open/close it *inside* the outer loop.

```
Do Until EMPLOYEE.AtEndOfStream
    '...
    Set DATA = fs.OpenTextFile("DATA.csv")
    Do Until DATA.AtEndOfStream
        '...
    Loop
    DATA.Close
Loop
```

Alternatively (if the file is sufficiently small) read it into an array once and have the inner loop iterate over that array.

```
DATA = Split(fs.OpenTextFile("DATA.csv").ReadAll, vbNewLine)

Do Until EMPLOYEE.AtEndOfStream
    '...
    For Each line2 In DATA
        '...
    Next
Loop
```

---

Side-note 1: creating multiple `FileSystemObject` instances in your script is pointless. Create a single instance at the beginning of your script and use that instance throughout the rest of the code.

Side-note 2: `Do While Not` is awkward. Use `Do Until` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot.